# Webview cannot load https URL Xamarin Droid

Tags: xamarin.android

I am currently using a `WebView Xamarin Android` in NewsDetailView to load the content of a News includes: html text and http/https URLs of picture

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/LighterGray"
  android:clickable="true">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/LayoutMargin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But WebView can not load pictures with `https url`.
I've already set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"` and added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true` in AndroidManifest.xml

This is code in View:

```
public class NewsDetailsView
    {
        private WebView _webView;

        public string WebViewContent
        {
            get { return _webViewContent; }
            set
            {
                _webViewContent = value;
                LoadHtmlString();
            }
        }

        protected override void InitView(View view)
        {
            base.InitView(view);
            _webView = (WebView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.webview);
            _webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = false;
            _webView.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.NoCache;
            _webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }

        private void LoadHtmlString()
        {
            _webView.LoadData(WebViewContent, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        }
```

This is a pattern of content:

```
Table 2:</strong>&nbsp;Time to feed pet MTF</span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px;"><img alt="Chỉ số thức ăn cho heo" src="http://nguoichannuoi.com/upload_images/images/kien-thuc-nha-nong/cs-thuc-an1.jpg" style="margin: 10px 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: 100%; height: 386px; width: 600px;"></strong></p>
```

Wonder if I need to set some thing more for `WebViewClient`? Have been doing a lot of research, but seems like it's hard to find tutorial for Xamarin Android then I've not found the right solution yet!

Need help!

Comment: Hello, in the title you said you are having problems with both HTTP and HTTPS urls but in the post, you mentioned only HTTP. Are you also having problems with HTTPS ?

Comment: yes It doesn't work with both Http & https @pinedax

Comment: I see you are using `_webView.LoadData()` if you are getting information from the web you should be using `_webView.LoadUrl();`

Comment: it has to be LoadData() cause the content includes both html text and url. Like Table 2:</strong>&nbsp;Time to feed pet</span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px;"><img alt="Chỉ số thức ăn cho heo" src="http://nguoichannuoi.com/upload_images/images/kien-thuc-nha-nong/cs-thuc-an1.jpg" style="margin: 10px 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: 100%; height: 386px; width: 600px;"></strong></p>

Comment: added android:hardwareAccelerated="true in Manifest.xml, my app now can read HTTP url, still looking for solution for HTTPS URL @pinedax

Comment: Try creating your own Client inheriting from the `WebViewClient` class and override this 3 methods: `OnReceivedError` , `OnReceivedSslError` and `OnReceivedHttpError`. Put a breakpoint in each one of them to see what the problem could be. 

Use this class to pass it to the `_webView.SetWebViewClient();` something like `_webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyOwnWebClient());`

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `OnReceivedSslError` method in `WebViewClient`.(I allow all SSL certificates just for the test. You should change the `MixedContentHandling` and SSL certificates by your needs ).

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
   {
        _webView.Settings.MixedContentMode =MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;
   }
        _webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

  public class MyWebviewClient:WebViewClient
  {

    public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
    {
      //  base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        handler.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.